# Empty Array being returned

Tags: arrays, mongodb, go, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic app and I am currently stuck trying to retrieve an array back from MongoDB through Go. This is what the data in MongoDB looks like.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "58a86fc7ad0457629d64f569"
},
"name": "ewds",
"username": "affe@dsg.com",
"password": "vdseaff",
"email": "fawfef",
"usertype": "Coaches",
"Requests": [
    "test@t.com"
]
}
```

I am currently trying to get back the Requests field one of the ways I tried was trying to receive the whole document using the following code.

```
//this is the struct being used.
type (
User struct {
    Name     string
    Username string
    Password string
    Email    string
    UserType string
    Requests  []string
}
) 
results := User{}
err = u.Find(bson.M{"username": Cname}).One(&results)
```

This only returns the following with an empty array.

```
{ewds affe@dsg.com vdseaff fawfef Coaches []}
```

Comment: Update the question to show the definition of `results`.

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: No error. Its meant to be giving back the array not an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data the `Requests` field has a capital `R`. The `bson` library that converts the mongo document to your struct type has this to say

https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Unmarshal

> The lowercased field name is used as the key for each exported field, but this behavior may be changed using the respective field tag.

So your options are to either add a tag to your `Requests` field or change your data to use lowercase `requests`. If you choose the tag option it would be like

```
Requests []string `bson:"Requests"`
```

Comment: Thank you so much.